Identifying Test-Only RPC Arguments
I am trying to identify test-only rpc arguments in init.cpp and wanted to confirm if the test-only options are those with ArgsManager::DEBUG_ONLY with OptionsCategory::DEBUG_TEST, or ArgsManager::DEBUG_ONLY only?
